# Vulnerable when using swapExactETHForTokens

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv2

I thought that setting block.timestamp to a deadline prevents MEV sandwich attacks.But my question is does it do the work well?

````
        address destinationAddress,
        uint256 minAmountOut
    ) external payable override returns (uint256) {
        if (destinationAddress == address(0)) revert ZetaCommonErrors.InvalidAddress();
        if (msg.value == 0) revert InputCantBeZero();

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = wETH;
        path[1] = zetaToken;

        uint256[] memory amounts = uniswapV2Router.swapExactETHForTokens{value: msg.value}(
            minAmountOut,
            path,
            destinationAddress,
            block.timestamp + MAX_DEADLINE
        );

        uint256 amountOut = amounts[path.length - 1];

        emit EthExchangedForZeta(msg.value, amountOut);
        return amountOut;
    }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to prevent sandwich attacks is to set minAmountOut correctly, as this data represents the minimum amount of tokens the user is expected to receive.
To calculate this data you must use other uniswap functions such as getAmountOut (not sure if this is the right function just talking out of memory) that will caculate the expected amount. From this data you can add slippage(generally consider that above 0.5% you are at risk of being front runned). Then your transaction is safe from being sandwiched. I don't think transaction deadline protects you from front running in any way.